# What was preventing move constructor to be used for overload resolution if this is the only possible one?

Tags: c++

Consider this snippet : OnlyMoveable can be built only with default constructor or move operation.

In this special case, at least for me, it seems obvious that there is no ambiguity and that constructing k shall call the move constructor.

Why automatic rvalue reference cast is not something in the standard ? That would have save many "verbose" std::move when manipulating move only types.

What would be in risk or unclear if such cast was done when no ambiguity was possible ?

```
struct OnlyMoveable {
    OnlyMoveable() {}

    OnlyMoveable(const OnlyMoveable& other) = delete;

    OnlyMoveable(OnlyMoveable&& other) {} 
};

void dummy ()
{ 

    OnlyMoveable defaultCtor;

    OnlyMoveable j(std::move(defaultCtor));

    OnlyMoveable defaultCtor2;
    // Do not compile, because attemps to call the copy ctor. Ok, but well, why the compiler in this special case where there is no
    // other overload than the move, can automitcally perform the rvalue reference cast ? 
    //OnlyMoveable k(defaultCtor2);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the existence of a copy-constructor, this initialization won't compile:

```
OnlyMoveable k(defaultCtor2); // error
```

It might seem reasonable that this would call the move constructor. However, this has the major problem, that `defaultCtor2` would be in a valid but unspecified state. This is dangerous and the language doesn't do this for you automatically, which is a good thing.

Of course, as the programmer, if you know that you never need to use `defaultCtor2` again, or at least you won't read its value, you can use an explicit `std::move` to tell the compiler to use the move constructor:

```
OnlyMoveable k(std::move(defaultCtor2)); // ok
```

Comment: Agree,  but in the meantime, there is already in C++ many things that are at least as "dangerous" as this, (lambda capture per reference, implicit constructor calls, non virtual destructor on base class, virtual functions that are inoperant if called during ctor - the list is not exautive... )

Comment: @sandwood That's true. Are you suggesting that because there are other dangerous things the language lets you do, it should allow all dangerous things?

Comment: Not really. My question was indeed , is there other thing (then potentially dangerous code..) that would prevent the automatic rvalue cast.

Comment: Well, it's the language rules that prevent it, but I believe the motivation is at least in part, to not allow dangerous code.